# held broken packages - unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management

Hopefully someone can help out, I have tried pretty much everything the online resources sugested but just hit a dead end, also having entry level knowledge is making this very painful.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

I am trying to install a package but running into below error

```
   root@librenms03:/# sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev pkg-config cmake libssh2-1-dev libicu-dev zlib1g-dev g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).
g++ set to manually installed.
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu4).
pkg-config set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libicu-dev : Depends: libicu66 (= 66.1-2ubuntu2) but 66.1-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8) but 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@librenms03:/#
```

there is nothing "onhold" checked
tried apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
tried aptitude install libssl-dev
tried numerous other things that take me nowhere.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thank you

```
also:

    root@librenms03:~# apt policy libssl-dev
libssl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8
  Version table:
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8 500
        500 http://mirror01.name.com/ubuntu/current focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror01.name.com/ubuntu/current focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirror01.name.com/ubuntu/current focal/main amd64 Packages
root@librenms03:~
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy libssl-dev` to your question.

Comment: thanks, has been done

Comment: Looks like your private mirror is stale, showing only older packages. Refresh your mirror, then run `apt update` again, then try your install again.

Comment: thanks, how do I refresh mirror?

Answer (score 1):

The source you are drawing on to obtain your packages, `mirror01.name.com` is outdated.

- It has `libssl-dev` version `1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8`
- The normal 20.04 repos have `1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10`

Based on your comment

> Thanks, how do I refresh mirror?

I assume you are not the owner/operator of this mirror.  You can either contact the owner/operator and get them to refresh it, or (perhaps easier), switch to a different mirror that is kept up to date. A list of all the mirrors is here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Once you switch, prepare for a massive software update and upgrade.